# Changing CSS Animation anchor point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following page (see image)
[image]

When I click the red button, I want a div to animate when it shows to the user. However, I want the animation to come from the button. Right now the animation comes from the center of the page.

Here's the code I have

```
@keyframes fadeInScale {
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutScale {
    0%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.fade-scale-in {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeInScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}

.fade-scale-out {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeOutScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

When I click on the red circle, the user sees an overlay page (which is actually a div with class overlay that is absolutely positioned). I add fade-scale-in class to the div (with class overlay). The div then transitions from the center of the screen and grows to fit the user's screen. I want it so that the div transitions from the red circle. Can I use transforms to make this happen?

Here's the code. As you notice, when you click on the yellow circle, the div animates from the center and not from the yellow circle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e4g71y4m/3/

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for us? It will be much easier for us to help you that way..

Comment: Question was updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding [`transform-origin: top left;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) to the `.overlay` element. (Don't forget the prefixes (`-webkit`, `-moz` etc.)

```js
var overlay$ = $('.overlay');
overlay$.bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e) {
  console.debug('test');
  if (e.animationName !== undefined && e.animationName == "fadeOutScale") {
    overlay$.addClass('hide');
  } else if (e.originalEvent.animationName !== undefined && e.originalEvent.animationName == "fadeOutScale") {
    overlay$.addClass('hide');
  }
});

$('.click').on('click', function() {
  overlay$.removeClass('hide').addClass('fade-scale-in');
});
$('.click-again').on('click', function() {
  overlay$.removeClass('hide').addClass('fade-scale-out');
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInScale {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutScale {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.click {
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fade-scale-in {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeInScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}

.fade-scale-out {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeOutScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">Click me</div>
<div class="overlay hide">
  Test
  <div class="click-again">Click me again</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the circle is at coordinates 1280px by 720px on the page.

Comment: Do you mean that you want that the transition will start **exactly** from the circle? You can set `transform-origin` by pixels..